# Why related products are not working in joomla/virtuemart?

Tags: php, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am working with joomla 2.5 and virtuemart 2.0. When I tried to add related products it searched and showed many products but clicking on it doesn't saved any products as related. I checked table

```
 #__virtuemart_product_relations
```

but it doesn't have any record, however I added some rows to it with product ids but still it didn't worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself exploring all joomla virtuemart tables. I'm posting answer here may be it can help others. Actually the table to store related products is

> #__virtuemart_product_customfields.

If you are not able to add related products from joomla administrator then insert rows to this table. You need to add only 3 fields i.e

> #### 1.virtuemart_product_id (enter here id of the product related for)
>
> #### 2.virtuemart_custom_id (enter here 1)
>
> #### 3.custom_value (product id of the related product).